# gatttool LTK, IRK, GAP doubts?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatttool

I am using `bluez` for writing a BLE application. I have read the source code of `gatttool`. I have few doubts regarding it and `bluez`.

1. What does `sec-level` in gatttool means? How it is related to security mechanisms of BLE Core specification (`Just Works`, `Passkey` and `OOB`)? How it is related to various security modes and levels of BLE?
2. How can i initiate bonding and pairing using `gatttool`? (You can
   point our command line arguments to command `gatttool`).
3. How can i access `GAP` profile using `gatttool`?
4. Is `service discovery` integrated in `gatttool`?
5. How can i manage/access peer's and own LTK and IRK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to build you application around gatttool and what's included in it.

Bluez5 exposes interfaces in the DBus. Using this dbus api and with the dbus bindings in the language of your choice (C, python, C#Mono) you can pretty much do everything =)

You can find a description of the dbus api exposed by bluez here :
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

You can find the source code of bluetoothctl (a tool that you can use for pairing, connecting, services discovery, gatt attributes reading & writing etc) here : https://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/client/main.c

bluetoothctl was built using GLib GDBus (dbus bindings for Glib in C) and you will find code examples for pretty much everything.

Comment: Can i get GDBus GLib in openwrt?

Comment: I'm not sure about it but I found this issue on the openwrt github : https://github.com/openwrt/packages/issues/1497

It mentions using bluetoothctl in openwrt, which means you can get GDBus Glib and the bluez dbus-api. The issue is dated to 2015 so I guess you can expect it to be solved and bluetoothctl working.